# React datepicker onchange keypress problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker

I use react-datepicker in my project. When I press the key, it completes automatically input. What do I need to change to work correctly like input?

Here is the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-hopper-jm4gx

Comment: what behaviour would you like? do you want the picker to stay open after click?

Comment: @DMcCallum83 no, when I choose date on picker input value change this date and also I can keypress on keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `customInput`, Once you remove it, it will work fine

```
<div className="custom-calendar">
  <span className="calendar"></span>
  <DatePicker
    ref={ref}
    name="birthday"
    dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    disabled={disabled}
    popperPlacement="right-center"
    locale="tr"
    selected={startDate || value}
    showMonthDropdown
    showYearDropdown
    onChange={(date) => onChangePicker(date)}
    yearDropdownItemNumber={100}
    maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 0)}
    scrollableYearDropdown
    autoComplete="off"
  />
</div>
```